# Bulk import / update data for Partner Community license users

Tags: partner-communities, partner-portal, bulk

Is there any way partner community users can bulk update the data back to salesforce? Please advise if there is any tool available that can help.

More details - The partner users are the vendors that use community to access FSL objects ex. WorkOrder, service appointments and they need to fill out the fields ex. Number, currency, text fields etc. They should be able to export it using report and do the modification to the data using excel/sheets and import it back.

Comment: Hi M P. I'm not sure it's clear what you are asking here. Could you edit your question to flesh out what you're trying to do?

Comment: @DavidReed I think OP’s question is around data load for partner users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_loader.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) for this purpose. Partner Community Users can use Data Loader to be able to bulk upload records.

You will need to make sure that the profile/permission set for such Partner Users have the permission `Enable API` enabled. Refer to this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205643&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) for details on this topic.